# Animate view on button click android

Tags: android, animation

I have a button and on that button i wanna slide a view below.That view contains 2 buttons to open camera and gallery.To achieve this i have used translate animation but i  am not getting the desired result.I want only that much part of the view to be visible as Slides down.

Anim Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="-10%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

Code

```
public class Slide extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slide);
        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Animation slide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Slide.this, R.anim.top_slide);
//
                linearLayout.startAnimation(slide);
                linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Image
[image]

i want the slide should occur from below the + image but its not happening

XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/butt3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/bton3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/butn3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/cb" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need slide animation, what you actually want is object animation

Code

```
    Button bt = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.test);
    bt.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {

            ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight (), 500);
            anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.height = val;
                    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }
            });
            anim.setDuration(1000);
            anim.start(); 
        }
    });
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/test"

        android:background="#fff333"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/butt3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/bton3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/butn3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/cb" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why you are setting linear layout visibility to true ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67111/discussion-between-anuj-and-murtaza-hussain).