# Hide and Show views in ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created and android application in that I want to hide and show views in ListView using Custom Adapter.

My Code is:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_estimate, null);
        btn_dots = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_dots_itemEstimate);
        ll_2 = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.ll_2_itemEstimate);
    }

    btn_dots.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            if (ll_2.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                ll_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                ll_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

    return vi;
}
```

[image]

When click on Dots it not hides the layout.

Thanks.

Comment: I have recently answered this type of **question**.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27524689/1061944

Comment: have you got any solution? plz post i need help

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have faced the same problem and solved it using ExpandableListView. I am pasting the code below

```
public DefaultContactListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cont> List2) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.contactList = contactList2;

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int parent, int child) {
        return child;

//      return glossariesList.get(Sub_List.get(parent) ).get(child);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int parent, int child) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return child;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int parent, int child,
            boolean lastChild, View convertview, ViewGroup parentview)
    {
//      String child_title=(String) getChild(parent, child);
        if(convertview==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertview=inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout_default_contact_screen_child, parentview, false);

        }

        return convertview;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return contactList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return contactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int parent, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parentview) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //String group_title=(String) getGroup(parent);
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.layout_default_screen, parentview,false);

        }



        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Expandable listview.
This link may help you

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class First_Activity extends Activity
{
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<Item> arrayList= new ArrayList<Item>();
    Adapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_actiivty);
        listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


        Item item = new Item();
        item.setText1("1");
        item.setText2("2");
        item.setSelected(false);
        arrayList.add(item);

        Item item1 = new Item();
        item1.setText1("1");
        item1.setText2("2");
        item1.setSelected(true);
        arrayList.add(item1);

        Item item2 = new Item();
        item2.setText1("1");
        item2.setText2("2");
        item2.setSelected(true);
        arrayList.add(item2);


        adapter = new Adapter();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
            {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, 1).show();
                for (Item item :arrayList){
                    item.setSelected(false);
                }
                arrayList.get(position).setSelected(true);

                System.out.println(arrayList.get(0).isSelected());
                System.out.println(arrayList.get(1).isSelected());
                System.out.println(arrayList.get(2).isSelected());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });



    }
    public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        public Adapter() 
        {

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return arrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
                holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.text1.setText(arrayList.get(position).getText1());
            holder.text2.setText(arrayList.get(position).getText2());
            if(arrayList.get(position).isSelected()==true)
            {
                holder.text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView text1;
            TextView text2;
        }

    }
}
```

javabeen get set

```
public class Item 
{
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    private boolean isSelected;

    public String getText1() {
        return text1;
    }

    public void setText1(String text1) {
        this.text1 = text1;
    }

    public String getText2() {
        return text2;
    }

    public void setText2(String text2) {
        this.text2 = text2;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

}
```

Main XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Row XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="30dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Override your click listener with this

```
btn_dots.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            if (arg0.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                arg0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                arg0.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: One line : `(arg0.getVisibility() == View.GONE) ? arg0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);`

Comment: you can use this alternate way also :)

Comment: With Less character one line: `arg0.setVisibility(arg0.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);`

Comment: @ツFellinLovewithAndroidツ :) He is trying to hide another view, not the button. And using if-else you make your code more readable than using turnary operators.

Comment: I think user will not upvote or reply to any answer. Its wastage of time to giving comments.

Comment: Hello friends I want to hide LinearLayout not Button.

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this in one line code:

```
btn_dots.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        arg0.setVisibility(arg0.getVisibility() == View.GONE ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
});
```